# Is there an algorithm or approach to draw a smooth curve through 2D points?

Tags: curves, spline

They key point compared to typical spline or polynomial applications is that there is no element of time.

I have a sequence of points on a plane: (x1,y1), (x2,y2), ...

x is not time, and the points can loop back over each other, make a spiral, whatever.

In my application, when the points are looked at by eye, curves can be visualized (imagined), but the points do not sample along the curves with equal spacing.  Sometimes there are large gaps and sometimes the points are close together.

As a cartoon example:
[image]

Just a Powerpoint hand drawn example here, I'd like the curve to be smooth and continuous.

Comment: Lagrange interpolation? It might be a little wonky, though...

Comment: Have you tried Bézier curves?

Comment: @Somos, the points have order, I don't need to learn it.

Comment: Is there a level of smoothness you need? Techniques can be slightly different depending on if you need it to be C^0, C^1, C^k, etc. In general, you may want to look at splines (piecewise polynomials with matching derivatives at the endpoints).

Comment: Catmull-Rom spline with centripetal parametrization.